# Partial .csproj Files

Tags: c#, csproj

Is it possible to split the information in a .csproj across more than one file? A bit like a project version of the `partial class` feature.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can not have more than one master csproj. But because the underneath wiring of the csproj is done using msbuild you can simply have multiple partial csproj that import each other. The solution file would see the most *derived* csproj.

**project1.csproj**

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    ....
</Project>
```

**project2.csproj**

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="project1.csproj" />
    ...
</Project>
```

**project.csproj** - this is the main project that is referred by the solution file.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="project2.csproj" />
    ...
</Project>
```

Bottom line is that using msbuild **Import** feature you can have partial csproj files where each one would contain definitions that the main project (project.csproj in my example) would use.

---

Visual Studio will show a **Security Warning for *project*** dialog when you open your changed solution or project file. Choose the option **Load Project Normally** and press **OK**. When opening the solution again later the warning will not be shown because the configuration to **Load Project Normally** is stored in the **suo** file.

Comment: +1 this works with Visual studio 2022 and doesn't seem to show any warnings (I extracted certain project settings into multiple `.targets` files as [recommended here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022#remarks) and placed them in the same folder as the main project file which imports them).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can split information across several files. You can use [Import Element (MSBuild)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx).

Note that Visual Studio will give you [annoying security warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228217.aspx) if you will try to open project file that includes other project files.

Useful linky from MSDN:

[How to: Use the Same Target in Multiple Project Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171464.aspx)

Note that external files have **.targets** extension by conventions.

Comment: You can choose to Load Project Normally and the next time the project will open without the warning. This is stored in the suo file.

Comment: I know, but suo files usually not stored under source control.

Answer (score -3):

Well you can have multiple projects combined into one large solution, but I don't think that is quite what you had in mind as each project has to be a complete project in that case.