# how to configure all C# project in a solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution which contains a lot of C# projects, how can I change the configuration of all projects very quickly, like I want to change the output folder from bin to MyBin. I know C++ property sheet can do the similar thing but C# doesn't have property sheet.

Comment: You can search and replace through all the csproj files.

Comment: Is this the standard solution for my problem?

Comment: Yes... Because there really is no UI for this. The .NET tradition is just to use `bin` and `obj` directories.

Comment: Surely you only need to change the entry assemblies? All the references are copied to the dependent bin folder on build (unless you specify otherwise).

Comment: The output folder is just an example, I may also want to change some other value like .NET framework version and so on..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a common 'partial' project file to store common stuff.

Move all the stuff that you want to be changed simultaneously into a stand-alone .proj file, e.g. `common.proj`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>Debug</OutputPath>
    <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Than use msbuild [import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/92x05xfs.aspx) declaration to 'include' common part into every project in your solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="common.proj" />
</Project>
```

MsBuild imports work more or less in the same manner as C++ includes: before a project is built all the import directives are replaced with the content of the imported file. Now you can change your common properties just in one file - `common.proj`

There's one important thing to mention: VS caches included project files, so you'd have to reload all the projects after applying a change to `common.proj` file (so I suggest building from command-line when you actively change `commom.proj`)

We use this approach to manage code-analysis settings (as they are supposed to be the same across all the projects in the solution).

Answer (score 3):

You have to define new `Build Configuration`, which can be copied from *Release* or from *Debug* or constructed all manually. After you can customize for every project it's option *in regard of that custom build you just created* and you done. This is done, naturally, only once. After, whenever you choose that custom build all properties chosen for every single project in solution will be set with the properties you want.

[image]

Comment: If I read the OP correct, he doesn't want to do it on a per-project basis, he wants to configure all the projects in one go at once.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: yes. BUt this is a way to do that. You *one time* that do for every single project in solution, and after everything works just switching between different configuration options.

Comment: Tigran - yes, it is the way, but only if you want to confine yourself to VS UI. If you dont care and if you understand how VS Projects and MSBuild are related to each other, you don't really have to and whole set of new options are open to you. What VS UI gives you by default is not always the best, and sometimes some customization must be done. It's actually quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

- Rightclick on ALL projects in the solution, one-by-one.
- Click 'unload' on each
- then click "edit XXX.csproj" again on all of them

You will now have many XMLs opened as text files.

Now use the Find&Replace (control-shift-H if you use default shortcuts), and set:

- Find what: `OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath`
- replace with: `MyBin\Debug`
- Look in: `All open documents`

and hit `Replace All`.

Then do the same with `bin\Release` and `MyBin\Release`.

Then save all XMLs, then right-click on every project and choose "reload".

You can do the same in any text editor or any command-line find&replace utility like `sed`. If you ave any, use them instead - it will save you from rightlicking/unloading all projects.

You can also exploit the fact that CSPROJs are just MSBuild files, so you can create a 'configuration' MSBuild script that will be included each of your C# projects, and which will define extra variables like 'common output path' etc. But while this certainly works (I've did it a few times), it will most probably screw up some PropertySheets in the VS UI in the most natural way, for example, if you use this to override/setup the OutputPaths, then the VS UI wil display empty or broken output paths and trying to use the VS UI to correct/change them will in turn overwrite your smart settings that read them from common config file. Obvious, isn't it.

EDIT: here it's quickly explained: [Partial .csproj Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157149/partial-csproj-files), however, please read my comments below too, just in case.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I know how to change the configuration by editing the xml project file, and I also know how to change them in the VS GUI. What I want to achieve is to modify a simple value and then all projects using the value will be changed, for example, I originally use .NET framework 4.0 for all projects, and now I want to use 4.5

Comment: The only way to do it is like I've already said - by using the MSBuild's "import" directive in .csproj file. You will create an additional "half-project" file that will set some common properties, and then each of your project will "include" that special file. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157149/partial-csproj-files Observe and take special care about what they say about "most derived" files. If projectA includes projectB which includes projectC, and if projectD includes projectC too, then you should **only** have projectA and projectD attached to the Solution in VS IDE.

Comment: Note that the extra projectB and projectC does NOT need to end in .csproj. You can "include" any file that is in correct XML/MSBuild format. This means that you can name them differently and include them in the Solution too, but NOT as projects, but rather as simple XML files. This will make editing them a little easier. However, you must still be very careful: the VS IDE will often not notice any changes you make to those extra files unless you reload the solution/projectA/projectD. Fortunatelly, it's only IDE problem. The "Build" option will always read everything properly.